# É possível desenvolver sites com C/C++?

Tags: php, c, c++

Eu sei um pouco de PHP, mas vejo que em sites de conteúdo, as vezes dá umas travadas e etc.

Pesquisando, vi relatos (bem superficiais) de que é possível desenvolver aplicações web com C/C++, e que essas, por sua vez, teriam muito mais performance do que as php, que são de linguagem interpretada.

Gostaria de saber se isso é verdade. Caso alguém possa ajudar, por favor, grato.

Comment: Voce pode fazer qualquer coisa com c++, drivers, sistemas operativos, aplicacoes. Aplicacoes web nao sao excepcao. Se sao mais eficientes? Isso é baseado em opinioes

Comment: Você pode desenvolver sites em C/C++ mas vai exigir muito mais esforço do que se você usar uma linguagem mais adequada a esse tipo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Isso também é baseado em opinioes. Há semelhanca de outras linguagens, também existem bibliotecas em c++ que facilitam o desenvolvimento de servidores, seguindo até por exemplo o padrao MVC

Comment: https://github.com/ipkn/crow

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sim, é possível sim. Mas quase ninguém faz. Geralmente o ganho não vale o esforço, que é muito maior.

E mais, se a pessoa não dominar todo processo de desenvolvimento, dominar cada minúcia da linguagem, pode ter um resultado bem pior. Linguagens não fazem milagres. Elas podem permitir que o programador obtenha o resultado desejado, se ele souber o que está fazendo.

Todas as linguagens de programação *mainstream* podem ser usadas para desenvolver websites, já que o que chamamos de sites são páginas de textos. Toda linguagem pode gerar textos. Esses textos precisam ser usados por um servidor HTTP. Todo servidor HTTP pode chamar um executável e obter esse texto de alguma forma. Claro que se a linguagem puder se comunicar de forma mais eficiente com esse servidor, melhor. Existem bibliotecas para C/C++ que ajudam nisso. Note que é comum esses servidores HTTP serem escritos em C ou C++.

A linguagem de programação não é o problema.

## Travadas

É possível que essas travadas estejam relacionadas com seu problema que é bem complexo. Mas também é possível que seja porque não está usando o PHP de forma adequada. Aí mudar de linguagem não resolverá qualquer problema, pode até ocorrer o contrário. O PHP é muito fácil, é mais difícil fazer algo errado nele. Mas vejo que muita gente faz. PHP é uma das linguagens mais usadas para desenvolver sites, fazem coisas complexas, e não trava.

Eu até tenho críticas ao PHP, mas quase tudo para web dá para desenvolver com ele. Nem sempre será a linguagem mais adequada, mas em coisas simples costuma ser. Mesmo que não seja a mais adequada, ainda será razoavelmente adequada.

O que muitas vezes as pessoas fazem quando precisam de performance extrema é passar para Java ou C# que são quase tão fáceis quanto o PHP e com performance muito melhor.

Eu poderia sugerir uma série de coisas que poderia fazer no próprio PHP para melhorar a performance, mas nem isso deve ser o problema. Deve ser algo relacionado ao algoritmo adotado. Então perguntas mais específicas sobre um problema pontual pode ser útil para achar o que está ocorrendo.

Mas reforço, que se não souber fazer tudo muito bem, não entender cada aspecto da computação, não obterá resultados bons em linguagem alguma. Talvez o caminho seja melhorar nesse ponto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Interessante explicação, me lembrou um professor de faculdade que dizia que tudo no desenvolvimento é possível, a questão é se é viável.

Answer (score 17):

Sim programação web em C/C++ **é possível**, isso inclusive remete ao início das aplicações dinâmicas na web. Nos anos 90 [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) com Perl para manipulação de texto e C/C++ para "processamento pesado" eram a norma.

A linguagem de programação, em média, não é o primeiro gargalo de um website. Latência de rede, IO, etc são fatores que pesam muito mais do que a linguagem na grande maioria dos casos.

É claro que o custo do processamento existe, bem como o custo de escalar um website para lidar com milhares / milhões de requests simultâneos... Além disso, com [estudos](http://www.aberdeen.com/research/5136/ra-performance-web-application/content.aspx) indicando que um atraso de um segundo pode impactar vendas em 7%, há incentivo econômico para otimização de *performance*.

Vamos assumir que você tenha um problema em que a linguagem de programação realmente se tornou relevante em relação aos demais gargalos de *performance* e escalabilidade. Mesmo nesse Universo as coisas não são tão binárias; a decisão não precisa ser entre linguagens puramente interpretadas vs puramente compiladas. De fato, o *sweetspot* para soluções *web* parece estar em máquinas virtuais com [compilação *just-in-time*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT). Essa foi a solução do Facebook para o PHP (veja [HHVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_Virtual_Machine)), de grande parte do desenvolvimento *enterprise* para grandes web sites (Java, .NET, etc) e mesmo para JavaScript (veja [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/)).

Você não precisa expor desenvolvedores às idiossincrasias do C/C++ para obter um ganho significativo de *performance*. De fato, mesmo partindo do pressuposto que uma solução em C/C++ devidamente otimizada sempre será mais rápida (o que não é verdade), a [lei dos rendimentos decrescentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminishing_returns) faz com que extrair essas últimas gotas de *performance* da linguagem em um mundo com tantos outros fatores dificilmente valha a pena.

Na grande maioria dos casos, acaba **não sendo viável** abrir mão de anos e anos de evolução das linguagens, ferramentas, técnicas e conhecimento acumulado pelas diversas comunidades especializadas em desenvolvimento web para escrever uma solução em C/C++. Frameworks para desenvolvimento web em C++ como [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main) e [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), independentemente de méritos técnicos, simplesmente não possuem a mesma tração de tecnologias em ecossistemas mais recentes.

Dessa forma, eu diria que desenvolvimento web em C/C++ é possível e existem aplicações em determinados nichos. Dito isso, vejo pouca chance desses tipo de desenvolvimento se tornar *mainstream*. O argumento do ganho de *performance* com C/C++ para "evitar travadas" não se sustenta e é bem difícil pensar em um bom motivo para escrever aplicações web em C/C++ em 2016.

Answer (score 7):

Como o @Maniero comentou, possível é, mas quase ninguém faz.

Isso é simples de entender: o C/C++ não tem esse foco de ser uma linguagem para Web.

Seria como tentar desenvolver um site com Pascal, COBOL ou outra linguagem com propósito diferente.

O C/C++ é uma linguagem que permite desenvolver qualquer coisa, mas existem linguagens mais indicadas para certos propósitos, assim como temos SQL para interação com banco de dados, e `R` para cálculos que auxiliam **Big Data**, há linguagens com suporte para o desenvolvimento Web, como PHP, Java e ASP/ASP.NET usando C# por exemplo.

No geral, você pode, mas teria que programar ou encontrar bibliotecas para coisas básicas que essas outras linguagens acima já tem.

Agora, sobre o seu problema de performance, culpar a linguagem é prematuro. Existem sites em ASP/VB que funcionam muito bem até hoje. Seu problema pode ser de rede, acesso a arquivo, tráfego, banco de dados, etc, uma monte de coisas que, independente da linguagem, vão deixar seu site lento.

Sugiro pesquisar mais a fundo e identificar onde está o problema. Muito provavelmente você vai conseguir resolver usando PHP e seu site vai ter uma boa performance.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo usar o C#. Eu comecei agora a estagiar numa empresa de programação web e estou a usar o ASP.NET e C#. Na faculdade aprendi C/C++, e C# é muito parecido e fáci aprender e o melhor é que poupa **muito** trabalho, pois há livrarias para tudo, incluindo para aplicações web, e o melhor é que podes usar o mesmo código para desenvolver para várias plataformas (ex. Android ou iOS) usando Visual Studio, que é grátis na versão comunitária.

Comment: Não gosto do C# mas é digno de nota que o Stack Overflow é escrito em C#.

Answer (score 0):

O componente crítico, que é o servidor Web em si, já é escrito em C ou C++.

Quanto ao código de aplicação, você vai gastar 100 vezes mais para desenvolver em C do que em PHP ou Javascript. De fato a página vai ter umas 3x mais performance em termos de CPU. Basta pegar uma máquina melhor na nuvem, por alguns dólares a mais por mês, para empatar a performance.

Só por este raciocínio já fica difícil justificar o gasto adicional. Mas tem mais.

O principal gargalo da performance Web é a rede (internet). Velocidade e principalmente a latência. Trabalhar o acesso de rede, usar CDN, usar cache para objetos estáticos, tudo isso vai dar resultados muito mais expressivos num primeiro momento.

Certamente sua aplicação Web usa um banco de dados. A performance desse banco vai ser um gargalo de performance muito antes do código da sua própria aplicação. Num site grande e movimentado, é aqui que você vai gastar o grosso do seu orçamento.

Um site Web costuma ser muito dinâmico, mudanças todo dia, desenvolvimento contínuo. E isso  não combina com C/C++, combina com linguagem interpretada, que você não vai usar só porque é facinha ou porque tem programador barato no mercado; vai usar porque ela é produtiva, porque ela vai permitir que você largue o trabalho à noitinha em vez de ter de virar noite.