# É possível criar programas compilados para WEB?

Tags: aplicação-web, característica-linguagem

Tratando-se de programação para `WEB`, é possível se desenvolver sistemas para `WEB` utilizando linguagens de programação compiladas, como `C++`, por exemplo? Ou para `WEB` somente são aceitas linguagens dinâmicas? Se for possível, quais linguagens compiladas podem ser utilizadas para criação de aplicações `WEB`?

Comment: Relacionado: [É possível desenvolver sites com C/C++?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171613/3117)

Comment: É possível desenvolver para Web com linguagens compiladas, mas não sei se é possível fazer uma lista de linguagens que permitem isso até mesmo pq se for ler a resposta da outra pergunta poderá ver que de certa forma qualquer linguagem pode ser usada para desenvolver web, só que algumas não são feitas para isso e te dará muito trabalho para adaptar. Talvez seja uma duplicada.

Comment: Sim, porem dependendo da linguagem, vai ficar por tua conta implementar o protocolo HTTP via socket, para que tua aplicação consiga se comunicar com o browser.

Comment: Praticamente qualquer coisa com suporte a socket serve para fazer servidor de página, email, websocket, ftp, etc. (e entendo que já respondido em [É possível desenvolver sites com C/C++?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171613/70) - a pergunta é de C, mas a resposta abrange o que foi perguntado)